# WCF remove the default response

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service whose default response looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body/>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want it to be totally different, e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema' 
                   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance'>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <ns1:methodResponse xmlns:ns1='urn:MyService' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
           <message href='cid:success'/>
       </ns1:methodResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried creating the response manually as a string and then added `Response.Write(xml)`.

The problem is that the default response (the first one) is also sent to the client so I get both responses.

How do i stop the WCF sending that unwanted response?

Comment: Semantically, the single difference in second response is tag methodResponse and its inner xml. Do you want to add this tag or you need to name namespace prefix to be exactly the same?

Comment: I just need to replace the default XML data with verbatim string containing the preferred XML. I don't need to change namespace nor headers. Is it possible?

Comment: i followed some tutorials and came with this http://ideone.com/bFbnGk however i don't know how to make it working (probably i don;t know how to add the inspector into web.config) and i still get the default response. THX

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to *replace* the response by [implementing 
IDispatchMessageInspector and modifying the message in BeforeSendReply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - using the class from [the example you mentioned](http://ideone.com/bFbnGk):

```
public class CustomInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel,
    InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        reply = ChangeResponse(reply);
    }

    private Message ChangeResponse(Message oldMessage)
    {
       // change message
    }
}
```

Then you need to create the supporting classes:

```
public class CustomExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new CustomBehavior();
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomBehavior);
        }
    }
}
public class CustomBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.OfType<ChannelDispatcher>())
        {
            foreach (var endpoint in dispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                endpoint.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomInterceptor());
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

This then allows you to declare the inspector in your service configuration: add this text to the `<system.serviceModel>` section (replace `Your.Namespace` with the actual class namespace):

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <!-- Replace default response -->
    <add name="CustomExtension"
          type="Your.Namespace.CustomExtension, Your.Namespace, 
                Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Finally, add this new behaviour extension to the service behaviour. You will need to replace: `defaultBehaviour` with the actual name, which you will find in `<services><service name="YourService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour"> <!-- < that's the name you want -->`

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehaviour">

      <CustomExtension/>
```

Comment: Hmm where i put this method of Message type? I am not even sure what of those is my custom XML which is a variable of string type (verbatim) e.g.

Comment: var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema' 
                   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance'>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <ns1:methodResponse xmlns:ns1='urn:MyService' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
           <message href='cid:success'/>
       </ns1:methodResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" ;

Comment: Hmm though it makes a perfect sense the response remains the same. I suspect the web.config http://csharppad.com/gist/1df60a78f2bac27f1459 please let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: F1 F1 :) could you please send me a working example? Just a basic WCF project with the fix applied? Will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I'm on holiday and a long way away from WCF. Can't do anything before next week..

Comment: Have a nice holiday :) see ya next week