# Rename Default Result TAG from WCF Response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Is there a way to rename the default result TAG generated by WCF?

```
<EvaluationsResult>
    <a:Evaluations>
         <a:Evaluation/>
         <a:Evaluation/>
         <a:Evaluation/>
         <a:Evaluation/>
      </a:Evaluations>
</EvaluationsResult>
```

From the above response returned by WCF, can we configure it to use any other name? or even remove it?

Comment: this might be a duplicate question of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264597/wcf-remove-the-default-response

Comment: Message inspector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731692/change-the-wcf-soap-response-xml

Comment: Is there any other way?. if the OperationContract name is Evaluations, the  response from wcf will be wrapped like the following

  <EvaluationsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <EvaluationsResult>

I want to change the text for EvaluationsResult